# Angular 4 Can't bind to 'dragula' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular, single-page-application, ng2-dragula

I'm struggling with binding [ng2-dragula](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula) to [AspNetCore SPA template](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/). Tried everything, but still getting:

```
Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'dragula' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
<div>
<div class='wrapper'>
<div class='container' [ERROR ->][dragula]='"first-bag"'>
<div>Drag/drop item 1</div>
</div>
"): ng:///AppModule/DragulaComponent.html@7:31
at syntaxError (C:\Users\...\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:36125:34)
at ...
```

Has anyone used ng2-dragula in AspDotnetCoreSpa?

dragula.component.html

```
<div>
 <div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='container' [dragula]='"first-bag"'>
   <div>Drag/drop item 1</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

dragula.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DragulaModule, DragulaService } from 'ng2-dragula'

@Component({
   selector: 'dragula',
   templateUrl: './dragula.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['../../../../node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.min.css']
 })
 export class DragulaComponent {
}
```

app.module.client.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DragulaModule } from 'ng2-dragula';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { sharedConfig } from './app.module.shared';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: sharedConfig.bootstrap,
    declarations: sharedConfig.declarations,
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        DragulaModule,
        HttpModule,
        ...sharedConfig.imports
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

app.module.shared.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';
import { DragulaComponent } from './components/dragula/dragula.component';

export const sharedConfig: NgModule = {
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        DragulaComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: 'dragula', component: DragulaComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
};
```

Comment: can you add your component code?

Comment: @FRECIA - just updated my post with the actual code

Comment: A little confused. Why you put "selector: 'dragula'", is this causing some ambiguity here as DragulaModule has 'dragula' as a directive?

Comment: @wannadream - changed selector name to 'dragging', but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

try to import `DragulaModule` in you app module(top level module)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using a module base structure(as below):

[Click : Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUJvX.png)

In this application there are modules like dashboard, dragula..etc.

In this case if you want to add dragula drag and drop (ng2-dragula), what you have to do is,  add `DragulaModule` in the `app.module.ts` using 
`import { DragulaModule } from '../../node_modules/ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula';`

once you add like this and if you try to use `[dragula]='"bag-something"'` in the `dragula.component.html`, which is the html file, still it will give the error `Can't bind to 'dragula' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.`

So the solution is add `DragulaModule` in the module's `xxx.module.ts`file.In this given case you will have to add in the dragula module's `dragula.module.ts`file.

Note: when import `DragulaModule` the path to the `ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula` may differ depending on your project structure.

Comment: It's all because of server-side-prerendering, check out my post on [GitHub](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula/issues/737)